# How to ignore .env file from .gitignore for laravel5.2

Tags: git, laravel-5, development-environment

I have written a line

> **.env**

in my .gitgnore file.but still it is not being ignored while the push.
My .gitignore file is in root directory of project folder.

Comment: Is that `.env` file already present in the repository?  If so, you'll need to first `git rm --cached` that file before the `.gitignore` rule can take effect.

Comment: Thanks for reply,i did try same also but still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after adding file name in .gitignore, you have to run:

```
git rm -f .env
```

It will never appear after in `git status`, no matter what modification you do in it.

A SUGGESTION, If you do not have good knowledge of unix commands and git, please save your .env file somewhere before playing with it.

Comment: Did you add "git" in command or you simply ran `rm -f .env` ?

Comment: added git
Copy and Paste
git rm -f .env

Comment: I am not sure how can it delete a file..one more question, did you look into the folder itself and didnt find .env or you are saying that it deleted because it appeared so in terminal? because terminal shows what has been ignored as deleted if it was already existing on remote directory.